# Crawl text on webpage that is not showing in html code

Tags: python

How can we extract the text on [this](http://www.thaibma.or.th/EN/BondInfo/BondFeature/Issue.aspx?symbol=BAM226A) webpage

The text such as 'TH6159032601' do not appear in the html code hence I am struggling to get the text through conventional scraping methods e.g. selenium, requests. Anyone knows how I can scrap these information?

Code in html

```
< td >< p class="" id="lblIsinTh" >< / p>< / td>
```

instead of

```
< p class="" id="lblIsinTh ">TH6159032601< / p >
```

Thank you

Comment: Look into beautiful soup library

Comment: I did use beautifulsoup.. it returns me the html without the texts i am looking for. Am I using beautifulsoup wrongly?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @Cuong driver.get('http://www.thaibma.or.th/EN/BondInfo/BondFeature/Issue.aspx?symbol=BAM226A') 

isin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lblIsinTh']").get_attribute('innerHTML')

Comment: @Cuong including the beautifulsoup portion

isin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lblIsinTh']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='home']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = bs(table, 'html.parser')

tr = soup.find_all('tr')
tablist = [] #emptylist
for i in tr:
    td = i.find_all('td')
    rowlist = []
    for i in td:
        rowlist.append(i.text)
    tablist.append(rowlist)

print tablist

the printed stuff are empty for most parts of the code... matches the missing text in the html code

Comment: @zee Try to put your driver to sleep for couple of seconds or use wait until "lblIsinTh" appears.

Comment: If u enter that link onto the browser, it takes a couple of seconds for TH6159032601 to show up. Therefore, u should use explicit or implicit wait on driver. Then start searching for that text.

Comment: @Cuong tried.. it didnt work.. code is still empty.. thanks though!